# Webpack hot-reload with remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

I'm wondering if there is a way to make hot-reload work while developing on a remote machine. Here's my setup: I have a remote vm that runs a webpack dev server. Locally I connect to my remote machine via ssh and change files there. Weback watches for file changes and recompiles accordingly, however the browser page doesn't refresh. Say my vm is hosted on https://example.com, locally I open this page in the browser and can see my project. Is there a way to make this page refresh for me, when files are changed (and webpack recompiles) on the remote machine? Maybe I can create a script that subscribes to webpack recompilations and does `location.reload()`?